# How do you select your starter Pokemon before a match?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When playing as Pokemon trainer, I heard it's possible to pick your starting pokemon. So far I've only seen Squirtle as the starter. How do you change that?

Can you also prevent your pokemon from cycling on death? I essentially want to play only as Ivysaur if possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change Pokemon Trainer's starter from the character select screen by clicking the Pokemon in the top-right corner of the trainer's portrait. Alternatively, [as scohe001 mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/342325/181240), you can also press **Y** to swap pokemon.

[image: Changing starter pokemon to Ivysaur]

As for your second question, there is unfortunately no way to disable Pokemon cycling on death. It will always cycle between Squirtle, Ivysaur, and Charizard when you respawn.

> That being said, the longer you wait on the floating platform after you respawn, the shorter your invincibility period will be. So if you're trying to switch back to your previous Pokemon, I'd strongly suggest getting back into the game as soon as possible to make use of a longer invincibility period to switch.
>
> [Via scohe001](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/342325/181240)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to clicking the Pokemon with your virtual hand, you may also press the **Y** button to cycle through them.

As Steven mentions, there is unfortunately no way to prevent cycling on death. That being said, the longer you wait on the floating platform after you respawn, the shorter your invincibility period will be. So if you're trying to switch back to your previous Pokemon, I'd strongly suggest getting back into the game as soon as possible to make use of a longer invincibility period to switch.

Comment: Do you mind if I add the tip for swapping with Y to my answer?

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro as long as you credit me, I'm all for having a canonical answer with all of the info in one place!